# How to get first top five with mysql

Tags: mysql, integer

How can I get the 5 first bits of an Integer?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Do you mean like `i & 0x1f`?

Comment: your title and description does not match at all.... could you be more clear...?

Comment: @jjreina - Asking a top 5 is something completely different from asking the first 5 bits of an integer. Wich one is it?

Comment: Have you tried reading the relevant documentation? Regardless of whether you actually want first five bits or first five rows of a result, your question is very trivial and would be explained in the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/).

Answer (score 3):

Top 5 rows in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 5
```

Top five bits of an 32-bit integer:

```
(a >> 27)
```

Top five bits of 32-bit integer field in MySQL:

```
SELECT (field >> 27) FROM table_name
```

[Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

[Bit Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html)

Comment: We still don't know what OP really wants.

Comment: @juergend - Why is this not what OP wants?

Comment: The message says `the 5 first bits`, which I think should be the lowest 5 bits, rather than the most significant bits (then, again, the title says `first top five`, but doesn't specify 5 of what)